# AWS S3 Lambda trigger not able to copy Video files greater than 5 mb from my source into destination bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have an AWS S3 Bucket, event Trigger with the option selected "All objects create events".
When a video file of lesser than 5mb comes into the source bucket via NODE JS SDK lambda it successfully copies into the destination bucket. But when the size is more than 5 MB it fails to copy.

cloud watch logs: Appears well with 'Start', 'End', and 'Report'. For successfully copy I have a console log " successfully copied", which doesn't appear for a failed copy.

My memory setting is Memory: 256 mb and Epherimal storage: 1024 MB.

Copy action is done by Node js :

```
if ((event.Records[0].eventName) === "ObjectCreated:Put" ){
            await s3.copyObject(
            params, function (copyErr, copyData) {
                if (copyErr) {
                    console.log("Error: " + copyErr.stack);
                } else {
                    console.log(`succesfully copied);
                }
            }).promise();
```

Note : Uploading to the s3 source bucket is done from NODEJS SDK `s3.upload`

Also , strangely Tried manually uploading to the AWS S3 Source bucket, which works for copying.

Any suggestions?

Tried manually uploading to the AWS S3 Source bucket, which works for copying.

Comment: You will need to use a **multi-part copy**. Search for that term and your preferred language/framework and you'll see some examples.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation s3.upload "Uploads an arbitrarily sized buffer, blob, or stream, using intelligent concurrent handling of parts if the payload is large enough."

That means that if the object is large enough will be uploaded in parts, when all parts are uploaded, Amazon S3 assembles these parts and creates the object.

In this scenario the corresponding event will be "**ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload**" and not "**ObjectCreated:Put**".

You can try considering **both events** in your if statement and see if it works.

Class: AWS.S3 upload:
[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property:~:text=Uploads%20an%20arbitrarily%20sized%20buffer%2C%20blob%2C%20or%20stream%2C%20using%20intelligent%20concurrent%20handling%20of%20parts%20if%20the%20payload%20is%20large%20enough.%20You%20can%20configure%20the%20concurrent%20queue%20size%20by%20setting%20options.%20Note%20that%20this%20is%20the%20only%20operation%20for%20which%20the%20SDK%20can%20retry%20requests%20with%20stream%20bodies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property:%7E:text=Uploads%20an%20arbitrarily%20sized%20buffer%2C%20blob%2C%20or%20stream%2C%20using%20intelligent%20concurrent%20handling%20of%20parts%20if%20the%20payload%20is%20large%20enough.%20You%20can%20configure%20the%20concurrent%20queue%20size%20by%20setting%20options.%20Note%20that%20this%20is%20the%20only%20operation%20for%20which%20the%20SDK%20can%20retry%20requests%20with%20stream%20bodies).

S3 Multipart upload: [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/mpuoverview.html#:~:text=A%20CompleteMultipartUpload%20call%20to%20finish%20the%20process](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/mpuoverview.html#:%7E:text=A%20CompleteMultipartUpload%20call%20to%20finish%20the%20process).